# How to code a covariate with less observations than the dependent variable?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, predictor

I’m looking to test pre vs post differences in working memory (using R), and have a covariate (IQ) that was only measured once. My data frame looks something like this:

```
d <- tibble::tibble(time = c(rep("pre", 10), rep("post", 10)),
  wrking_mem = c(abs(rnorm(10, 50, 10.2)), abs(rnorm(10, 70, 13.5))),
  iq = c(rnorm(10, 100, 15), rep(NA, 10)),
  participant_id = as.factor(rep(1:10, 2)))
```

The R packages I’m using require that the # of outcome observations be equal to the number of predictor / covariate observations to fit the linear model or else you get an error.

Wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar situation, and what you did to solve the issue?

Any help is great - thanks!

Comment: How was the IQ measured? There are IQ test that involve the working memory.

Comment: @captcoma Thanks for the comment. In this case, IQ is a hypothetical stand-in variable for any covariate that was measured once in a repeated measures experiment. Apologies, as I should have specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your intervention is not intended to change IQ, then it might be a reasonable assumption that IQ is constant, so the IQ before can be used as the IQ after.

Comment: Thanks for this, @MaartenBuis. So simply repeating the same values a second time over sounds like the plan. Much appreciated!